# Probability distribution with a skew

Tags: probability

If I had levels of some product from 1-4 and each one has a 25% chance of being made, but 10% of the time they'll make one lower and 10% of the time they'll make one higher (the lowest one can only go 10% higher and the highest one can only go lower) wouldn't each thing still have a 25% chance of happening?  I don't know what go google to figure this out or how I should be thinking about it.  A nudge in the right direction would help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are describing a *Markov chain* with *initial state* $(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25)^T$ and *transition probabilities*
$$
P = \begin{pmatrix} 0.9&0.1& 0& 0 \\ 0.1 &0.8& 0.1 &0 \\ 0& 0.1 &0.8& 0.1 \\ 0 &0 &0.1& 0.9 \end{pmatrix}
$$
In that case, yes: $(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25)^T$ is the steady state  of this chain, because 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0.9&0.1& 0& 0 \\ 0.1 &0.8& 0.1 &0 \\ 0& 0.1 &0.8& 0.1 \\ 0 &0 &0.1& 0.9 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}0.25 \\ 0.25 \\0.25 \\0.25 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0.25 \\ 0.25 \\0.25 \\0.25 \end{pmatrix}
$$